# Why do I see so many comments in this format?

Tags: php, comments

I see so many PHP comments in the format of:

```
/**
 * (c) Copyright Someone 2009
 * legal crap
 * blorp
 */
```

Is this just by convention, or is there a reason? I thought it was just a way that some people did it, but I am  now wondering after I discovered that my syntax highlighter does this:[It's red without asterisks http://img.skitch.com/20090628-ef9riek8m5d75udssrqewhkasn.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090628-ef9riek8m5d75udssrqewhkasn.png)

This only happens when I've started to use this format, and then stop using it. Why are comments done this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) comments. Comments starting with `/**` are used by documentation generators (by convention) to create documentation for the project. Here is a [quick start guide for phpDocumentor](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html).

Comment: Can I just add... some development environments (eg. PDT) parse PHPDoc comments and so can provide 'intellisense' surrounding function parameters, class members etc. (on top of the whole phpDocumentor thing).

Comment: I can confirm that PHPEd also uses them for Intellisense. PHPDoc is probably the feature I like PHP for the most.

Answer (score 7):

Many documentation generators can read from formats like this.

This is also used by many IDE's to help with coding. (for example Zend Studio and others)

```
/**
 * Title
 * 
 * @author Me
 * @copyright 2009
 * @name test
 * 
 * @param int $foo
 * @return bool 
 */
function test($foo)
{
    return is_int($foo);
}
```